# Simperium multiple users accessing data

Tags: ios, simperium

In the Simperium documentation/help section there is the following text:

> All the data that is created seems like it must be tied to a user - is
>   that correct? Is it possible to have data that isn't tied to a user -
>   say a database of locations or beers?
>
> Yes, though this isn't very clear yet. You can create a public user
>   (i.e., a public namespace) with an access token you share with other
>   users of your app so anyone can read/write to that namespace.
>
> It's possible to limit this to read-only access as well if you need to
>   authoritatively publish data from a backend service.

Is there an actual example with this?

The scenario I have is as follows

1. My app will have a calendar
2. The primary user can add and remove data from the calendar
3. They will want to invite other users to add and remove data, my thought is that they can give them a token, the user can use their email address and this token to sign in

Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 0):

You're definitely on the right track, but a little too far ahead on that track. The scenario you described is a great fit for Simperium, but sharing and collaboration features aren't yet released.

The help text you quoted is for authoritatively pushing content, for example from a custom backend to all users of your app. An example of this would be a news stream that updates on all clients as new content is added.

This is quite different than sharing calendar data among a group of users who have different access permissions, which is actually a better use of Simperium's strengths. We have a solution for this that we've tested internally, but we're using what we've learned to build a better version of it that will be more scalable for production use.

There's no timeline for this yet, but you'll see it announced on your dashboard at simperium.com.

Comment: Hi Mike,  for relying during the holidays, I will look forward to the update.